# Model is not binding to ViewModel ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

In the GET edit function of my controller, I'm taking in the id as the parameter and finding the correct model. Everything populates as it should.
I want to turn around and generate a ViewModel from this model so I can add a few more fields to it, but as soon as I create an instance of the ViewModel with the already-populated model, everything remains null.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
        var un = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, User.Identity.Name);
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        Ticket ticket = db.Tickets.Find(id);

        var ticketViewModel = new TicketViewModel(ticket);

        if (ticket == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        List<TicketViewModel> TVM = new List<TicketViewModel>();
        var tl = (from TU in db.Users
                    where TU.sAMAccountName == un.SamAccountName
                    join UD in db.Departments on TU.DepartmentID equals UD.Id
                    select new
                    {
                        TU.Id,
                        TU.sAMAccountName,
                        UD.Name,
                        TU.DepartmentID
                    }).ToList();
        foreach(var listitem in tl)
        {

            ticketViewModel.UserID = listitem.Id;
            //ticketViewModel.DepartmentName = listitem.Name;
            //ticketViewModel.sAMAccountName = listitem.sAMAccountName;
            ticketViewModel.DepartmentID = listitem.DepartmentID;

        }
        ViewBag.CategoryID = new SelectList(db.Categories, "Id", "CategoryName");
        ViewBag.UserID = new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", "CanonicalName", ticket.UserID);
        return View(ticketViewModel);
    }
```

**TicketViewModel**

```
public class TicketViewModel
{
    public Ticket Ticket { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public TicketViewModel(Ticket ticket)
    {
        this.NoteHistories = new HashSet<NoteHistory>();

        Ticket = ticket;
    }   
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Subcategory { get; set; }
    public string Severity { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public string sAMAccountName { get; set; }
    public string Application { get; set; }
    public int WorkstationID { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Created_At { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Updated_At { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<NoteHistory> NoteHistories { get; set; }

}
```

***Ticket Model***

[image]

***ticketViewModel after new TicketViewModel(ticket)***
[image]

Comment: They're two different models? You set the `Ticket` class in `TicketViewModel`

Comment: You're kind of missing the point of viewmodels. You typically don't embed the entity within it - use something like automapper. Also, you wouldn't need the ViewBag - add those select lists to your viewmodel as well.

Comment: I thought the point of viewmodels was to combine a few different models into one and return just the one? Context, this is my first decent size ASP (not MVC) project and I'm learning as I go. 
And I was planning on adding the other items from the ViewBag to the ViewModel, but I wanted to get it working first.

Comment: What do you mean by "everything is null"? You sent your constructor a proxy to a Ticket object and that's what it has. You should consider not doing that though. Your VM would have fields that match your model and you'd use automapper or hand roll code that sets those fields.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's going to be null still. You are only ever setting three variables in the `TicketViewModel` class.

Here you are creating a new instance of `TicketViewModel` and passing the `TicketModel` as a parameter to the constructor:

```
var ticketViewModel = new TicketViewModel(ticket);
```

In the constructor you are setting the `Ticket` variable:

```
Ticket = ticket;
```

Here you are setting the `Id`, `Name`, `aAMAccountName` and `DepartmentID`

```
        ticketViewModel.UserID = listitem.Id;
        //ticketViewModel.DepartmentName = listitem.Name;
        //ticketViewModel.sAMAccountName = listitem.sAMAccountName;
        ticketViewModel.DepartmentID = listitem.DepartmentID;
```

and that's it. You're not setting anything else.

I did notice however that the above is in a `foreach`, so if there is more than one item in the list, they'll be overwritten.